# How do I implement transactions in Access?

Tags: ms-access, transactions

I am stuck implementing a transaction/rollaback feature on an access form.

Here's the stripped down outline of what I've done:

In the form's Load handler, I start the transaction

```
dbEngine.BeginTrans
gInTransaction = true
```

Then, there's a "Cancel" button, whose Click handler goes like

```
dbEngine.Rollback
gInTransaction = false
doCmd.close acForm, "frmName"
```

Finally, the form's Unload handler has:

```
if gInTransaction then
    dbEngine.CommitTrans
    gInTransaction = false ' just in case
end if
```

Now, there seem to be no effect on the form regarding the rollback. Pressing the "Cancel" button does not seem to rollback anything.

I also tried replacing dbEngine with dbEngine.workspaces(0), with no effect either.

So, the question is: how do I implement transaction in Access?

Thanks for any pointer into the right direction,
Rene

Comment: What DML statements (UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE) are you executing between the form load & close? How are the changes written to the database?

Comment: I don't *explicitly* write some dml statements, but access (or the form) does it for me by my filling out the (continouos) form and appending records. So, it would be all of the three mentioned dml statements: update, insert and delete.

Comment: In that case, it won't run under a transaction you initiated using `dbEngine.BeginTrans`. Statements executing using `dbEngine.Execute` et al will run under a transaction if you had a call to `BeginTrans` prior to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Researching these transactions, I found this link promising:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248011

Yet, there seem to be some other issues with it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can implement transactions on a form, where updates are made on a recordset (with beforeUpdate and afterUpdate events), while transaction is linked to the execution of an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE command sent to the database.

EDIT: if your idea is to be able to manage all changes made to a continous form at once, you have 2 different solutions:

1. The first one is to attach a
   disconnected ADODB recordset to your
   form, and call the 'batchUpdate'
   method once all your changes have
   been made. Though I haven't check
   the doc, I guess you'll be able to
   catch exceptions that can happen at
   this stage through the connection
   object.
2. The second one, which is the one we implement in our applications, is to have the client work on a copy of the original data. On the client side, we keep track of all inserts, deletes and updates made on the form. Once the user validates its changes, the client generates 'on the fly' a bunch of SQL instructions corresponding to the changes made, and send them to the database. It is then very easy to send these instructions in a transaction (either one transaction per line or one for all changes). It took us a while to fine-tune this solution, but it was worth the job. Form validation is now a unique function used on every form of our apps. The function even allow 'one form to multiple tables' validation.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Shahkalpesh the updates to the form will not be part of the transaction. You could get your form to do these by instead of using a bound form use an unbound form so you have control over when the IO is done.

You could do this a few ways but my preferred method is to load the details into the form onload and then have a save button that fire a sub that saves those details back to the DB. I Also normally setup a public variable call bDirty and change it to true when ever a control is undated that way you can warn the user if they try closing the form before saving changes

Comment: I think your solution depicts one that is possible for a 'single record' form, but not for a continouos form. But in my case, I have to solve it for a continouos form.

Comment: I did not see the part about it being a continuous form in your original question. It would still be possible if you had the continuous form as a sub form and "Posted" the statements to be executed back to the main form. You could then execute the statements when you want. It would be very hacky but would work. Is there another option other than a continuous form?

Answer (score 0):

I [posted a code example for how to use transactions in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078432/do-we-have-transactions-in-ms-access/2079362#2079362) a little over a week ago, but it was not designed for working with data edited in a bound form. Basically, with bound forms, you don't have the same control you do via other interfaces. This is both a feature and a drawback, depending on what you're trying to do.