# Sql transaction and rollback in asp .net can it be used for MS Access

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

Sql transaction and rollback in asp .net can it be used for MS Access

Comment: I think this is asking the same thing, and there is an accepted answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078432/do-we-have-transactions-in-ms-access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes as though stated by [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208950%28office.12%29.aspx) but you may use another type like OleDBTransaction not SQLTransaction!
So Give it a try!