# Update MS Access db in C# best way

Tags: c#, sql, database, performance, ms-access

My update code:

```
 for (int i = this.MedaxilGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex; i < this.MedaxilGridView1.RowCount; i++)
 {
     // KartsifarishiGridView-dən id götürüb ona uyğun sorğumuzu yazırıq.
     sqlSorgu = "UPDATE customer set medaxil_status = '0' WHERE id = " + 
                 this.MedaxilGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["id"].Value;
     //Sorğunu icra edirk.
     Program.esas.sqlSorguCommand.CommandText = sqlSorgu;
     Program.esas.sqlSorguCommand.Connection = Program.esas.bazayaQosul;
     Program.esas.sqlSorguCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
     MedaxilGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Empty;

 }
```

Row count : 18286

This version takes 5 minutes

How do I make it faster?

Comment: how do you extract the id's to operate with ?

Comment: you mean you have to update all the row with medaxil_status = '0' ?

Comment: You can try using a stored procedure. It will work a bit faster. Before that you can try executing the single query "UPDATE customer set medaxil_status = '0' WHERE id = " + 
                 this.MedaxilGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["id"].Value;" with some real value and check how long it takes. This will help you realise which part takes too much time.the loop or the sql itself.

Comment: You should also look into parameterized queries to make sure you're code isn't vurnerable to sql-injection.

Answer (score 1):

You should think which query you use to extract the id's and use it directly into the update, so you call the database once:

```
"UPDATE customer set medaxil_status = '0' WHERE id in (select xxx xxx xxx)"
```

if you want to update **all the rows**, just **remove the where clause** and call the statement **just once**.
If you have just an id list, maybe chunking the calls by using alwais the IN clause will reduce the number of queryes and hopefully the overall execution time.

Comment: @Ozgur Dogus Abi bir misal koy bakim

Comment: All interlinear not. Selected row - last row

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BeginExecuteNonQuery` for that, that will save you the connection initiation overhead, by opening one connection, and batch executing all of your queries.

A full example from MSDN can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b6f9k7k.aspx)

Furthermore, I would advise you to start using [SQL Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx)

Comment: @FelicePollano Yes you can. All I want to 0

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enclose your loop in a Transaction ? This speeds up MS Access update operations.

Take a look on this sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078432/do-we-have-transactions-in-ms-access) that shows how to use MS Access Transaction in C#