# MS access 2003, sql script

Tags: sql, ms-access, transactions

How can i execute inside MS Access 2003 sql script. For example - multiply inserts or updates.

I try to execute:

- insert into tbl (field1, field2) values (1,2), (3,4) - *after (1,2)- must be semicolon*.
- insert ... values (1,2,3,4) - *number of arguments not match*
- insert ...(1,2); insert ... (3,4) - *extra symbols after semicolon*.

Possibly I can execute external script file?

Or i must write VB/JS/Other script, which will call queries one at a time?

Comment: Follow this similar kind of question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078432/do-we-have-transactions-in-ms-access

Comment: Thanks. I search, but not found that question.

Comment: @Prasanna that link is about transactions, not the same thing at all as executing multiple statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Access will only execute one sql statement at a time, you cannot put a semi-colon and then write the next statement, so yes, you will need another script or a CSV, which can be inserted directly.