# Access SQL Transactions?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've read that MS Access supports transactions but when I try to use it, I get the error **Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'**. All I'm writing out is...

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO MyTable1(Field1, Field2, etc...) VALUES (Value1, Value2, etc...)
    INSERT INTO MyTable2(Field1, Field2, etc...) VALUES (Value1, Value2, etc...)
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

This is in a stored query in Access. Why is it giving me this error if it is supported?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208950(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: What version of Access are you using

Comment: [Do we have transactions in MS Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078432/do-we-have-transactions-in-ms-access) Look at the answer provided by @David-W-Fenton - Quick answer: The jet engine does not support transactions as a stored query.

Comment: Oh....., I did not read that.

Comment: It does, but not as a stored query. The MS documentation isn't fully clear on that part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transactions are not supported in MSAccess when you are using them in a query.  Try firing a function to create those queries, which you can do in a module and have it run on PageLoad or even an OnTimer event.  You can use the BeginTrans and Rollback commands inside the module.