# Cant get TransactionScope working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

How can I use `TransactionScope`? I can hardly find any info about that.  My project wont recognize `TransactionScope` and turns red when I try to call it. I tried with `using System.Transactions.TransactionScope;` but it didn't work either.

Also once its get worked, will `Method_A();` to `Method_C();`  being within transaction then? Meaning if anything would fail e.g. in `Method_C();`, would everything rollback including `Method_A();`and `Method_B();`? That's the behavior I want.

```
private void method_A(){/* doing tons of db stuff */}
private void method_B(){/*...*/}
private void method_C(){/*...*/}


protected void Insert_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(TransactionScope tran = new TransactionScope())
    {
        Method_A();
        Method_B();
        Method_C();

        tran.Complete();
    }
}
```

Using C#, ASP.NET and ms Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TransactionScope is not available for Microsoft Access, so you cannot use it.

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078432/do-we-have-transactions-in-ms-access) for alternative implementations of Transaction Scope.

As for the transactional scope, see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243155(v=office.12).aspx)

Relevant Quote:

> Within one Workspace object, transactions are always global to the Workspace and aren't limited to only one Connection or Database object. If you perform operations on more than one connection or database within a Workspace transaction, resolving the transaction (that is, using the CommitTrans or Rollback method) affects all operations on all connections and databases within that workspace.

This means that everything you do on the Access-File within your workspace is within the transaction, even if you access the workspace from somewhere else while the transaction is still going.

Keep [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243806(v=office.12).aspx) in mind:

> The behavior of transactions with Access databases differs from the behavior of ODBC data sources, such as Microsoft SQL Server. For example, if a database is connected to a file server, and the file server stops before a transaction has had time to commit its changes, then your database could be left in an inconsistent state. If you require true transaction support with respect to durability, you should investigate using a client/server architecture.

Comment: it doesn't show how to implement transaction via C#, or would it work if I simply add something like `cmd.CommandText = "BEGIN TRANSACTION";` *and execute it*.. C# code and methods in between.. `cmd.CommandText = "COMMIT [TRANSACTION | WORK]";`  `cmd.CommandText = "ROLLBACK [TRANSACTION | WORK]";` ?